# Django-cms ckeditor permissions

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-cms

We are developing a django-cms (django 1.8, cms 3.2) site including the ckeditor. Logging in with admin, no problems. But when I set a user to staff and give PagePermissions, I get the error "**You do not have permission to edit this plugin**", when opening the editor in cms. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

please update the details:

Where i understood it might be because of this:

The problem is that after migrating to `ckeditor`, the relevant permissions in `auth_permissions`, as stated above, point to the wrong content type id. To fix this problem look up the id of the `ckeditor`plugin content type:

```
select * from django_content_type where app_label = 'djangocms_text_ckeditor';
```

and the original text plugin:

```
select * from django_content_type where app_label = 'text';
```

Now update the relevant permissions:

```
update auth_permission set content_type_id = <new ck text plugin id> where content_type_id = <old text plugin id>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Non superusers must also be provided permission on individual plugins, for them to be able to add/edit/delete them.
Non superusers must also have "use structure mode" permission (starting 3.1+) to enter structure mode in the frontend editor.
The best way to give users permission on pages is by using the "Permissions" item in the toolbar on the page you want to give permission to: it's the best way to be sure to provide all the needed permissions on the correct page.